Model probabilistic time evolution from vector field distribution
Given an axis-aligned grid${}^1$ $x_1 , \ldots , x_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{2n\times 2n}$ be the means and covariance matrix and assume we have a vector field $X : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which is drawn from a normal distribution $\mathcal N (\mu, \Sigma)$ at $x_1 , \ldots , x_n$.
Now the question is, whether we can model the flow given by the vector field starting at a fixed point explicitly, or more formally:
Given $x_k, ~ 1 \le k \le n$, are there probability density functions $(f_t)_{t>0}$ that model the probability of where we end up after following a vector field drawn from above's distribution?
I know this is somehow a soft question, but I don't know how to even start or where to look for a way of modeling this.
I'm also aware that this is too strong of a result to expect given we start with only discrete knowledge about the distribution from which to draw the vector field. But what if we were able to draw continuous vector fields?

${}^1$here, 'axis-aligned grid' means it is the intersection of an axis aligned rectangle with an axis-aligned lattice; the latter being $\alpha_1 \mathbb{Z} \times \alpha_2 \mathbb{Z} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} k_1 \cdot \alpha_1 \\ k_2 \cdot \alpha_2 \end{pmatrix} : k_1 , k_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ for some $\alpha_1 , \alpha_2 \in \mathbb R$.
